# Use KendoUI Mobile ListView template data inside id attribute

Tags: javascript, cordova, kendo-ui

How can I create a custom template for KendoUI mobile ListView where I can use the data as part of the HTML `id` attribute.

I've tried:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="foo">
       <li id="#:id"></li>
 </script>
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid template:'
       <li id="#:id"></li>
        ' Generated code:'var o,e=kendo.htmlEncode;with(data){o='\n                           <li id="'+e(id"></li>
     )+;}return o;'
```

When I put the inside the `li` tags it works, but I need it as part of the id.

Comment: I think you are missing the `#` at the end of your id assignment. Try: `id=#:id#`. See this example: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rowtemplate.html

Comment: thanks. Write and I accept

Comment: The template syntax is documented here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/framework/templates/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the # at the end of your id assignment. Try: id=#:id#. See this example: [demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rowtemplate.html](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/rowtemplate.html)